# write array in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, file-read

I have a csv file that contains a list of data points.

```
1.3
5.0
15.35
14.3
9.8
4.4
7.6
9.87
```

How can I write a python program that can read the numbers in the csv file and make them into an array x so that:

```
x=[1.3,5.0,15.35,14.3,9.8,4.4,7.6,9.87]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt genfromtext method from numpy.
More info on `numpy.genfromtext` is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

**Demo Code:**

```
import numpy as np
x= np.genfromtxt ('youData.csv', delimiter=",")
print x
```

**Output:**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
[  1.3    5.    15.35  14.3    9.8    4.4    7.6    9.87]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or the easiest solution in my experience and fastest CSV reading:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x=pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)
x=np.array(x.values)
```

Comment: You will lose the first value `1.3`, you would need to do `x = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)`